# PHPMailer won't send an email with attachment which is not already in the uploads folder(Only in production)

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, attachment

I'm making a contact us form on my website, I've used PHPMailer to handle sending the form to my email, everything was working fine on my local host and on a free online host (Heroku) that I was using to test the website. The issue started when the company published the website, the form won't submit when we attach a file which is not already in the uploads folder(or not with the same name of a file in the uploads folder).

Did this problem happen with anyone before, is it an issue with the code or the server or what ?

This is my code :

```
  $path = 'upload/' . $_FILES["personalCV"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["personalCV"]["tmp_name"], $path);   
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  try {
    //Server settings
      // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
      $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username   =// <SMTP username>
      $mail->Password   =// <SMTP password>
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port       = 465;
      //Recipients
      $mail->setFrom(<email>, <AS Website>);
      $mail->addAddress(<address>, <name>);
      $mail->addAddress(<address>, <name>);     // Add a recipient
      // Attachments
      $mail->AddAttachment($path);

      // Content
      $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
      $mail->Subject = 'New Job Application From The AS Website ( '.$position.' )';
      $msg = '<p> Name : '.$firstName.' '.$lastName.'</p>
              <p>Email Address: '.$email.'
              </p> <p>Phone Number: '.$phoneNum.'</p>
              <p>Position Appling For: '.$position.'</p>
              <p> Message: '.$message.'</p>';
      $mail->Body    = $msg;
      $mail->send();
      $successMsg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                      Message successfully sent
                     </div>';
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $failMsg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    Message not successfully sent, please try again
    </div>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why not mention the concrete exception message? Why would you expect it to work with absent files?

Comment: You're not doing any error checking, so you won't hear about any errors that happen! Base your code on [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: the problem is I don't have access to the published website so I can't really check the error there, and locally this issue don't even exist.

Comment: The problem is solved, it was an issue with the server's configuration

Comment: Instead of writing `[Solved]` in the title, please use Stackoverflow correctly and either write an answer and accept it, or delete this question if you don't think it'll help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, it was an issue with the server's configuration.